# Mostrar información ente dos campos (incluyendolos) y agregar una fila con el total de sumas de una columna

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estoy usando la informacion del siguiente archivo:

- [Archivo Csv ATP Men's Tour - Results of the ATP tour competitions since 2000](https://www.kaggle.com/jordangoblet/atp-tour-20002016/kernels)

  - [Archivo reducido para testeo, contiene desde Adelaide a Monte Carlo](https://pastebin.com/fZWrcMFB)

Para leerlo y mostrar uso lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import chardet
import numpy as np

### Si quieren usar el codigo de ejemplo, la siguiente linea
### tarda bastante en hacerse porque busca la codificación que usa el 
### archivo, ( si usan el archivo reducido es instantáneo)
### {'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}

with open('Direccion donde esta el CSV', 'rb') as f:
result = chardet.detect(f.read())

datos = pd.read_csv('Direccion donde esta el archivo', 
encoding=result['encoding'], low_memory=False)
df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
limpiarNaN = df.replace(np.nan, '0')
archivoConvertidoInt = limpiarNaN.describe(include = [np.number])
archivoConvertidoInt = limpiarNaN.replace("NR", "0")
archivoConvertidoInt['Wsets'] = archivoConvertidoInt.Wsets.astype(float)
archivoConvertidoInt['WRank'] = archivoConvertidoInt.WRank.astype(float)
archivoConvertidoInt.set_index("Location", inplace = True)

(archivoConvertidoInt.loc[['Adelaide' , 'St. Petersburg'], 'Series' : 
'Round']
.groupby(["Location", "Series", "Court", "Surface", "Round"]) 
["Series",].count())
```

Esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

Como ven me muestra informacion de las localizaciones de Adelaide y St. Petersburg.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ahora:**

1) Como puedo mostrar la misma informacion pero no solo de Adelaide y St. Petersburg si no de todas las localizaciones que hay entre ellas inclusives, si uso : para separar me da error de sintaxis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y 2) Agregando un sum al final puedo saber cuanto es el total de series, como puedo agregarlo como una nueva fila ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como para que quede algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la página que enlazas pide un registro para descargarse el .csv por lo que no puedo probar con tus datos. ¿Podrías subir a algún sitio (ej: pastebin) una versión abreviada del csv?

Comment: y no podrias recorrerlo mediante un ciclo for.. y en una variable ir sumando uno a uno las serias para obtener el total

Comment: @DiegoAvila Usar bucles para recorrer filas no es la mejor opción cuando usas pandas. Pandas tiene operaciones vectoriales que operan "de una vez" con toda la tabla, mucho más eficientes que usar bucles. La suma de hecho se obtiene con un simple `archivoConvertidoInt.sum()` La pregunta no es cómo calcular la suma, sino cómo añadir ese resultado al final de la tabla.

Comment: @abulafia ahi lo agregue a la pregunta "Archivo reducido para testeo, contiene desde Adelaide a Monte Carlo" es un txt, lo abri pase a csv y el codigo funciona ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El índice del dataframe (la columna "Location") no está ordenado, por lo que no están seguidas todas las filas de una misma localidad, lo que te impide usar `.loc["Localidad1":"Localidad2"]`, tienes que hacerle un `.sort_index()` antes.

Por otro lado creo que te sobran unos corchetes alrededor de el rango de ciudades.

Con el dataframe que has publicado de ejemplo, lo siguiente creo que hace lo que buscabas (he cambiado `St. Petesburg` por `Montecarlo`, pues St. Petesburg no estaba en el extracto que publicaste)

```
resultado = (archivoConvertidoInt
 .sort_index()
 .loc["Adelaide":"Montecarlo", 'Series':'Round']
 .groupby(["Location", "Series", "Court", "Surface", "Round"])["Series",]
 .count())
```

Genera un largo dataframe que empieza así:

[image: Principio]

y acaba así:

[image: Final]

Respecto a agregar una fila con el total, en principio debería ser tan simple como:

```
resultado.loc["Total"] = resultado.sum()
```

Pero el problema en tu caso es que al tener el dataframe un *multi-index* y agregarle una fila que no es *multi-index*, fuerza a que el resto del dataframe deje de serlo (y convierta cada índice en tupla). Para evitarlo, creemos esa última fila también con un *multi-index*, especificando texto para los cinco niveles del índice. Así:

```
resultado.loc[("Total", "", "", "", "")] = resultado.sum()
```

Ahora la tabla finaliza así:

[image: Con total]

Comment: Lo testee con el archivo original y funciona. Muchas gracias.